# PyGTK The function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk

I am trying to write a function to write text to a terminal window inside my application. But I am getting the above error.

Here's some of my code. This is GUI to play midi files. I am trying to display Opened file in my terminal window :

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import signal
import pango
import subprocess

textview = gtk.TextView()

class Teacher:

    result = ""
    def __init__(self):

        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_size_request(400, 200)
        window.set_title("The Improvisor")
        window.connect("delete_event", 
                   lambda w,e: gtk.main_quit())


        table = gtk.Table(4, 4, True)
        window.add(table)

        button1 = gtk.Button("Open")
        button1.connect("clicked", self.clicked_open_file)
        button1.show()

        button2 = gtk.Button("Play")
        button2.connect("clicked", self.clicked_play)
        button2.show()

        button3 = gtk.Button("Stop")
        button3.connect("clicked", self.clicked_stop)
        button3.show()


        fontdesc = pango.FontDescription('monospace')
        textview.modify_font(fontdesc)
        scroll = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scroll.add(textview)
        textview.show()


        table.attach(button1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
        table.attach(button2, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        table.attach(button3, 0, 1, 2, 3)
        table.attach(button4, 0, 4, 3, 4)
        table.attach(scroll, 1, 4, 0, 3)


        window.show_all()





    def clicked_play(self, widget):
        result = self.result

        if result == "":
            parent = None
            alert = gtk.MessageDialog(parent, gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, gtk.MESSAGE_INFO, 
              gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE, "Please Select a File")
            alert.run()
            alert.destroy()


        else :

            self.proc = subprocess.Popen(["timidity", result])


    def clicked_open_file(self, widget):
        chooser = gtk.FileChooserDialog(title="Open a file",action=gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                              buttons=(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,gtk.STOCK_OPEN,gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
        response = chooser.run()

        self.result = chooser.get_filename()
        self.insert_text(self.result)

        chooser.destroy() 

    def clicked_stop(self, widget=None):
        if self.proc:
            self.proc.terminate()
            self.proc.wait()

    def insert_text(text):
        textview.get_buffer().insert_at_cursor(text)


    def main(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.clicked_stop)
        gtk.main()
        return 0


Teacher().main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insert_text` method lacks the `self` attribute. Change it to:

```
def insert_text(self, text):
    ...
```

Remember: the `self` argument in Python is the current instance of the class and must be declared explicitly as the first argument of a method.